# RedirectToAction with nameof(NameofController) fails to locate the action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

According to the inlined documentation, `ControllerBase.RedirectToAction` takes both the action name and the controller name:

```
// Parameters:
//   actionName:
//     The name of the action.
//
//   controllerName:
//     The name of the controller.
public virtual RedirectToActionResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName);
```

Now, let's assume I want to redirect to the following action:

```
[Route("Whatever")]
public class WhateverController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("Overview")]
    public IActionResult Overview()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Naturally, I wanted to use the `nameof` operator:

```
[Route("Home")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("Something")]
    public IActionResult Something()
    {
        return RedirectToAction(
            nameof(WhateverController.Overview), // action name
            nameof(WhateverController) // controller name
        );
    }
}
```

But that call fails with the error `InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.`

I know I could hardcode the controller name to "whatever" instead of using the `nameof` operator, but is there a way to get the proper name from the class name?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/T4MVC/R4MVC/wiki/Documentation package

Comment: @MohammadDaliri can you add that as an answer? That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `nameof(WhateverController)` returns `WhateverController`, not (Whatever) that you and routing system expect.
You may use `nameof(WhateverController).Replace("Controller", "")` to get what you want.

Edit:
If all you want is not hard-coded controller/action names, Then it's better to use something like [R4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/R4MVC).

Comment: Wait, that's all? I expected the MVC framework to provide a way to do that instead of having to do it manually..

Comment: @Métoule, it won't, but you can get what you want by using [R4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/R4MVC).

Answer (score 2):

`nameof(WhateverController)` will return "WhateverController". `RedirectToAction` is expecting to take your controller's name in the form of "Whatever".
Using `nameof` instead of hardcoding strings is definitely good (in a lot of circumstances) but it looks like that's what's throwing you off in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a fan of extension methods because it pollutes the API in this case, but if you want, it is not the worst idea.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the word "Controller" from the string.
    /// </summary>
    public static string RemoveController(this string value)
    {
        string result = value.Replace("Controller", "");

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
nameof(WhateverController).RemoveController();
```

---

**A Better Approach**

Instead of extension method, create a base controller and put the method in it.

```
public class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the word "Controller" from the string.
    /// </summary>
    protected string _(string value)
    {
        string result = value.Replace("Controller", "");

        return result;
    }
}
```

If I think a method name serves no purpose, I sometimes use `_` but you can replace it with a name if you want such as `RemoveController`.

**Usage**

```
public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Index(string value)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(WhateverController.Overview), _(nameof(WhateverController)));
    }
}
```

You can see from above usage how `_` stays out of the way and improves readability. Again this is what I do so if you don't like it, you don't need to do this.